# Redirect users to other website with custom HTTP headers using PHP

Tags: php, http, redirect, curl, header

I'm trying to understand if even if this is possible. 
Below is incorrect PHP code, but it illustrate what I want to achieve.

redirect.php

```
<?php

set header ('Example-Header: someText')
Redirect www.example.com

?>
```

So for example if I had **mysite.com/redirect.php?url=www.example.com** this would redirect to **www.example.com** with the custom header **Example-Header: someText**.

I have tried cURL and some PHP code like header(Location: url) with no success. I have a CentOS Apache Web Server

Could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect a browser by using the `header` function to set a `Location` header.

There is no way for the server to tell the browser to send any HTTP header it would not normally send when it makes the subsequent HTTP request.

The closest you could come would be to act as a proxy server (i.e. to make the request to the second URL yourself, e.g. with cURL, and then relay the response back to the browser instead of redirecting)

Comment: This is right, but the question was not about removing default headers, but to add a "custom" header even in case of redirect - which should be no problem i'd say?

Comment: @dognose — I think you misunderstood my answer. I said nothing about removing default headers. I said that the browser would send the default headers and only the default headers.

Comment: Okay, then its wrong -you can send whatever headers you like,

Comment: @dognose — No. The server cannot make an HTTP response which instructs the browser what request headers to include in its next response.

Comment: Well, while a custom-header-RESPONSE is ofc. Possible - sending custom headers is ofc. not. (If that was the question, I missunderstood it)

Comment: I can trap my HTTP request using a intercepting proxy(Burp Suite) and I can modify HTTP headers which affects the response HTML. But I would like do this without a client proxy. So it's looking impossible to do this with code then?

Comment: You can do it with code … but that code must form part of a proxy. You can't do it with instructions in an HTTP response.

Answer (score -1):

When you're redirecting, there's no way to control how the browser performs the `GET` request to the target site.

The only way I can think of doing this is for your PHP code to perform the `GET` request itself, using `cURL`. It can then send whatever headers it wants, and return the response to the client. But this is not likely to work well, because any relative URLs in the response document will be relative to the target URL, but the client's browser will interpret them relative to your script's URL. You would need to scrape the document and update any embedded URLs appropriately.

Comment: That sets response headers. I'm pretty sure the question is about setting request headers after the redirect.

Comment: Correct. I'm trying to modify the HTTP GET Request

Comment: Oh, in that case I'm pretty sure there's no way to do it.

Comment: If you already know (on server side) the headers you want to SEND with the (next) GET-Request - why do you need that extra request?

Comment: I can trap my HTTP request using a intercepting proxy(Burp Suite) and I can modify HTTP headers which affects the response HTML. But I would like do this without a client proxy and create a website to do the work.

Comment: You can't always get what you want.

Comment: Not if you put restrictions on how you can do it. You can put a man on the moon, but not if you set the budget at $1,000.

Comment: @Barmar There was no constraint for the man to arrive alive :-)

Comment: @dognose I was going to poke holes in that analogy but you beat me to it :)